# How to display a map direction which fetches latitude and longitude from sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

HI all,

i have map application which stores the latitude and longitude of location in sqlite database.
Depending on the existing latitude and longitude saved in sqlite database,i want to display a new map.How is it possible.Can anybody help me in solving this problem.Thanks.

Comment: you want to show only one location or a couple of locations or a path from source to destination location

Comment: i want to show path from source to destination depending on my latitude and longitude values present in sqlite database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",sourcelocation.latitude,sourcelocation.longitude,destinationlocation.latitude,destinationlocation.longitude];
```